# rails generate model(s) through configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, models, rails-generate

There are possibilities to generate models (and migration) through a configuration file? I have so much table and i want create them (all the time) with a simple step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm holding all my migration commands in a bash shell file. This allows me to "recycle" certain parts, and prevents me from making typo's... Once a command has been run, I outcomment it, but keep it present in the file